# Multiparty dataset intersection count

Tags: public-key, algorithm-design, multiparty-computation, private-set-intersection, proxy-re-encryption

Typically, Private Set Intersection (PSI) protocols let you learn the subset of items on each party's dataset that are in the intersection. The problem in this case is a relaxation of these kind of constructions. I would like to learn only the number of elements on the intersection.

I could achieve this by using proxy re-encryption on a 2-party setting, however it is non-trivial (at least to me) to do the same on an n-party setting without disclosing the intersection of any parties subset.

I wonder if this problem has a specific name and whether it has been studied before (some literature you can point me to). Any idea on how to achieve this is also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem was studied under the name of *[private set-intersection cardinality](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~gts/paps/psi-ca.pdf)* (PSI-CA) by De Cristofaro et al. They give protocols for the two-party case both in the honest-but-curious and malicious setting, and the complexity grows only *linearly* in the size of the sets. A result for the multi-party case was given by [Egert et al.](https://www.cryptoplexity.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/media/crypt/publications_1/ACISPegert2015.pdf) using [Bloom Filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).

In case you are interested in only testing whether two sets are disjoint without revealing anything else then the problem has been studied by Kiayias and Mitrofanova and under the name [*private intersection predicate evaluation*](https://ifca.ai/fc05/p10.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for. If you have any recommendations for the multiparty case of PSI-CA, I am all ears! I

Comment: Added one result for the multi-party case. I would recommend going through [google scholar](https://scholar.google.co.il/scholar?cites=12259331805148157829&as_sdt=40000005&sciodt=0,22&hl=en) citations of these papers if you are interested in more recent results.